# Google Dataprep integration whith message brokers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataprep

Is it possible to read form Kafka or Google Pub/Sub in a Dataprep Job?

If so, any 'best practice' deployment considerations I should expect when the samples are edited on board an "oh so snappy, live and responsive" a la visual studio (minus the ability to purchase or download the tool) whereas debugging the production flow (same "type" of data") is performed on top of anything but such tools (coding Scala/Java on our favorite IDE)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a native way to read from a message system, like Kafka or Pub/Sub, directly into Cloud Dataprep.

I'd recommend an alternative approach:

1. Stream the data into BigQuery and then read the data from BQ
2. Write the stream data to Cloud Storage and then load the data

Both approaches will require writing the data to an intermediate location beforehand. I'd recommend BQ if you have needs for low latency, performance, or query-ability in the future. I'd recommend GCS for low-cost when speed is not critical.

Comment: My -main- concerns are neither cost nor speed, but more along the lines of consistency. That is, I want to be able to set up an environments where every message is processed  exactly once and in-order by the flow Dataprep deployed?